# $R$-mod as a full subcategory of $Ab^R$

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-groups

I'm studying Category Theory from "Categories for the Working Mathematician" by Mac Lane. I want to show that if $R$ is a ring, $R$-Mod can be described as a full subcategory of the functor category $Ab^R$.

My attempt: Let $G\subset Ob(Ab)$ be the collection of additive abelian groups. I tried to show natural transformations are $R$-module homomorphisms and the below diagram is commutative iff $\varphi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism where $G_{1,2}\in G$ and $h_{1,2}$ are group homomorphisms.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An $R$-module structure on an abelian group $M$ is given by a ring homomorphism $R\to \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb Z}(M,M)$, and the latter is the same thing as an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched functor $R\to  \mathbf{Ab}$, where we regard $R$ as a category with a single object whose endomorphism ring is given by $R$.

Comment: $R\to hom(M,M)$ for $M\in Ob(Ab)$ gives an $R$-module structure on $M$, I don't understand why $R\to M (M\in Ob(Ab))$ gives us this homomorphism  $R\to hom(M,M)$

Comment: Let $\varphi: R\to hom(M,M), r\mapsto \rho_r$. $r.m=\rho_r(m)$. Let $\psi: R\to M, r\mapsto m$. Then we have $\varphi : r\mapsto \rho_r $ where $\rho_r=?$ how can I relate it to $\psi$

Comment: How is $\psi$ defined?

Comment: $\psi$ is the functor that sends $R$ to object $M$

Comment: If $\psi$ is a functor so that $\psi: R\mapsto M$, from this we consider $R\to hom(M,M)$. But doesn't this give us functors from $R$ to $hom(M,M)$?

Comment: Recall how we define the category $R$: it is given by a single object $\ast$ with $\operatorname{hom}(\ast,\ast)=R$. Then a functor $\psi$ gives rise to a map $\operatorname{hom}(\ast,\ast)\to \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\psi(\ast),\psi(\ast))$ which is a ring homomorphism whenever the functor is $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched, hence if we set $M=\psi(\ast)$ we obtain the desired homomorphism $R\to \operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb Z}(M,M)$.

Comment: Thank you very much